# Is there a formal term for a "subset connected by comparability" in a poset?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Suppose I have a poset $P$. A subset $Q$ of the elements of $P$ has the property that, for any two elements $a,b \in Q$, $a$ is "connected to" $b$ through a chain of comparisons with the elements of $Q$. Hence, e.g., $$a > c > d > b$$ or $$a < c > d < e < b,$$ etc., with $c,d,e \in Q$.

I've been calling $Q$ a "topologically connected pocket in $P$", but I've been told that this expression is confusing.

I'm really not all that familiar with poset theory. Is there a more formal name for a subset with this property?

Comment: Just to clarify, in your second example, it's intentional that the $c$ to $d$ comparison is "greater than", different from all the other "less thans"?

Comment: Using transitivity, having a chain of comparisons $$a<c<d<b$$ is equivalent of saying that $a<b$. But if you allow chains with both $<$ and $>$, then it's different

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: Yes. The comparisons can go either way. Very specifically, the elements of $P$ are sets, $>$ implies superset, $<$ implies subset. Hence, I'm saying that any set $A$ in $Q$ can be "reached" from any set $B$ in $Q$ by jumping to supersets and/or subsets also in $Q$. For example, I can reach $\{a,b\} \in Q$ from $\{c,d\} \in Q$ if $\{a,b,c\}, \{c\} \in Q$ since $\{a,b\} < \{a,b,c\} > \{c\} < \{c,d\}$ .

Comment: So what you want to say is that $a$ is connected to $b$ if there exist $c_0,\ldots,c_n$ such that $a=c_0$, $b=c_n$ and $c_i<c_{i+1}$ or $c_i>c_{i+1}$ for each $i$.

Comment: @amrsa: Exactly! Specifically, I want to know what a subset that has this property (i.e. where any two elements are connected in this way) is called. Is there a formal name or term for it?

Comment: I don't know. But I would perhaps borrow from graph theory. In a simple graph I think we would say that there is a path between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @amrsa: So, in graph theory, the term would be a "connected subgraph". Would that also apply here?

Comment: I suppose that's right. (But I don't study graphs for a veeeery log time :-).)

Comment: So perhaps the name *connected sub-poset* would be alright.

Comment: @amrsa: It looks like "connected sub-poset" is correct. I've found a link [here](https://www.planetmath.org/connectedposet) that uses the term. Would you mind formally answering the question and including this link so that I can give you the checkmark? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you've found your name, but I so wanted it to include the word "zigzag", because that's such an evocative term for what the "path" looks like.

Comment: I do think something like "zigzag connected" would be a more fun term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every poset is a directed graph with a directed edge $a \to b$ whenever $a \le b$, and in a directed graph the concept you're looking for is called being [weakly connected](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeaklyConnectedDigraph.html) (as opposed to "connected," which is reserved for directed paths). If $Q$ is maximal with respect to this property then it is a [weakly connected component](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeaklyConnectedComponent.html). I think that term would be fine here although you might have to define it.

The corresponding concept also makes sense in a category; in this context the chain of comparisons you're describing is called a [zigzag](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/zigzag) which may be useful terminology. Zigzags are morphisms in the [localization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localization) of a category, where we formally invert some morphisms, and the operation here can be thought of as formally inverting all the morphisms in a poset regarded as a category. Of course you don't need to know any of this; this is just background to show that this is an important and relevant concept and not an ad hoc construction.